Need Help Creating a Simple Web Service with PowerShell on IIS - Getting HTTP Error 502.2
I'm trying to create a simple web service using PowerShell that will return a result when called. I want to host this web service on IIS, but I'm running into issues.
Here's what I've done so far:
I created a PowerShell script that outputs some JSON data.
I set up IIS to execute this script by adding a handler for .ps1 files.
I used the CGI module in IIS to handle the PowerShell script.
However, when I try to call the web service, I get the following error:

HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway

The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "".
I've made sure that my script outputs the necessary HTTP headers like Content-Type, but the error still occurs. I've also checked the event logs, but I'm not sure what to look for.
Has anyone successfully hosted a PowerShell script as a web service on IIS? If so, could you guide me on how to fix this error or suggest a better approach?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Web services are more commonly written in ASP.NET Core/Python/Java/Node.js/Go.

The most common issue is that the script might not be outputting the correct HTTP headers. Your PowerShell script must start by outputting the necessary headers, including the Content-Type and possibly a Status header. and make sure that the application pool in IIS has sufficient permissions to execute the PowerShell script. If the script is located in a directory that the IIS user cannot access, it will fail.

Try running using Postman which will automatically add HTTP headers.  If postman works you can check the complete http request in the Postman Control Panel.  Then add missing headers to you PS cmdlet to get code to work in PS.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
